# Mongoose set "id" property of document to be equal to "_id" of the document by default

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Model that needs to have "id" property. Since it needs to be unique, I want set its value to be the same as "_id" property of the document after creation. So, my Model looks something like this:

```
const modelSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: { type: String, unique: true },
    property_1: { type: String, unique: false }
    property_2: { type: String, unique: false }
    ...
  }
);
```

For now, I do this with 2 different queries, one for creation of document, and one for updating the "id" property with the value of "_id", after document is created.

```
Model.create({
    propery_1: value_1,
    propery_2: value_2,
    ...
}).then((document) => {
    document.id = document._id;
    document.save();
})
```

Is there a way to define my Schema to support this by default ("id" property will be automatically set to value of "_id"). Or can I replace this two queries with one that will have the same functionality.

Comment: `id` is a [virtual getter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) that returns the `String` value of `_id`. This happens automatically unless you specify specify `id` option for that schema/model to `false`, as in it's value is already the value of `_id`, just as a `String`. How/where are you trying to access `id`? If you mean that you aren't seeing `id` in JSON from an API response, you need to make sure you have [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) enabled and specify to have them returned in `toJSON`.

Comment: This is only the simplified Model of the real case. I need both the "id" and "_id" properties in my document, because the rest of the application is looking for "id" property. So, I need to set the "id" property to be equal to "_id" after the document is created. My current approach works, but I just want to check it I can do it in more simpler manner.

Comment: Once a document has been saved, you can immediately access `id`, you don't need to set it as mongoose does that automatically. It really is just a virtual property that that returns `String(_id)`. If you set a breakpoint in your application and inspect the document you will see that it has something like `get() id`. Have you tried just accessing `document.id`? Keep in mind, I mean it's available on actual documents, it won't be in JSON unless you specify `toJSON` and `toObject` accordingly.

Comment: I managed to solve it with virtual property. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by removing "id" field from the Schema, and defining virtual property "id". That way Mongoose will automatically add field "id" to the document. The code looks like this:

```
const modelSchema = new Schema(
  {
    property_1: { type: String, unique: false }
    property_2: { type: String, unique: false }
    ...
  }, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

modelSchema.virtual('id', {
  id: this.id
});
```

It is important to add `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` and `toObject: { virtuals: true }` so the virtual fields will be added to document by default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a single **id** property in the schema that duplicates the **_id** property.

```html
const modelSchema = new Schema(
  id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    default: function () {
      return this._id;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This causes a type error: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id').